# How can I specify how a file is opened with HTML?

Tags: html

I have always wanted to create a personal website on my computer where i could click on a title i wanted and have it start up the game in its respectable emulator. I have tried hrefs and hrefs in hrefs with no success. I want it to be on my flash drive and on it would be all the necessary emulators, roms, and code. I do not wish to have to keep setting the default program on each computer.
Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Games</title>
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center;background-image:url('Images/background.jpg');color:#D8D8D8;link="gold" alink="green" vlink="#BDBDBD">
    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/007.z64"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Golden Eye 007</font></a></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/Mario Kart 64.z64"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Mario Kart 64</font></a></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/mario64.z64"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Super Mario 64</font></a></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/Papermario.z64"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Paper Mario</font></a></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/Zelda.n64"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time</font></a></br></br>
    <a href="Rom/FFXII.bin"><font style="font-size:20px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std">Final Fantasy XII</font></a></br></br>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:540px"><h2 style="font-size:50px;text-align:center;Font-family:Hobo Std;color:#266EE1">Video Games</h2></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:535px"><hr style="width:295px;height:2px;background:#266EE1"/></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Website can not start a "native" program. You should find in-browser emulator and open it inside a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, this is not possible in modern browsers. Links aren't designed to open files, they are designed to redirect to other pages or download files.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks.  That also explains why it kept downloading the file.